# AKS via Terraform Error: Code="CustomRouteTableWithUnsupportedMSIType"

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

trying to create private aks via terraform using existing vnet and subnet, was able to create cluster suddenly below error came.

│ Error: creating Managed Kubernetes Cluster "demo-azwe-aks-cluster" (Resource Group "demo-azwe-aks-rg"): containerservice.ManagedClustersClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="CustomRouteTableWithUnsupportedMSIType" Message="Clusters using managed identity type SystemAssigned do not support bringing your own route table. Please see https://aka.ms/aks/customrt for more information"
│
│   with azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster,
│   on aks_cluster.tf line 30, in resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster":
│   30: resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster" {

```
# Provision AKS Cluster
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster" {
  name                = "${var.global-prefix}-${var.cluster-id}-${var.environment}-azwe-aks-cluster"
  location            = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "${var.global-prefix}-${var.cluster-id}-${var.environment}-azwe-aks-cluster"
  kubernetes_version  = data.azurerm_kubernetes_service_versions.current.latest_version
  node_resource_group = "${var.global-prefix}-${var.cluster-id}-${var.environment}-azwe-aks-nrg"
  private_cluster_enabled = true


  default_node_pool {
    name                 = "dpool"
    vm_size              = "Standard_DS2_v2"
    orchestrator_version = data.azurerm_kubernetes_service_versions.current.latest_version
    availability_zones   = [1, 2, 3]
    enable_auto_scaling  = true
    max_count            = 2
    min_count            = 1
    os_disk_size_gb      = 30
    type                 = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    vnet_subnet_id       = data.azurerm_subnet.aks.id
    node_labels = {
      "nodepool-type"    = "system"
      "environment"      = "${var.environment}"
      "nodepoolos"       = "${var.nodepool-os}"
      "app"              = "system-apps" 
    } 
   tags = {
      "nodepool-type"    = "system"
      "environment"      = "dev"
      "nodepoolos"       = "linux"
      "app"              = "system-apps" 
   } 
  }

# Identity (System Assigned or Service Principal)
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

# Add On Profiles
  addon_profile {
    azure_policy {enabled =  true}
    oms_agent {
      enabled =  true
      log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.insights.id
    }
  }

# Create Azure AD Group in Active Directory for AKS Admins
resource "azuread_group" "aks_administrators" {
  name        = "${azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name}-cluster-administrators"
 description = "Azure AKS Kubernetes administrators for the ${azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name}-cluster."
}

 RBAC and Azure AD Integration Block
  role_based_access_control {
    enabled = true
    azure_active_directory {
      managed = true
      admin_group_object_ids = [azuread_group.aks_administrators.id]
    }
  }



# Linux Profile
  linux_profile {
    admin_username = "ubuntu"
    ssh_key {
      key_data = file(var.ssh_public_key)
    }
  }

# Network Profile
  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "kubenet"
    load_balancer_sku = "Standard"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "prod"
  }
}
```

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to create a Private AKS cluster with existing Vnet and existing subnet for both AKS and firewall ,So as per the error `"CustomRouteTableWithUnsupportedMSIType"` you need a managed identity to create a route table and a role assigned to it i.e. `Network Contributor`.

Network profile will be `azure` instead of `kubenet` as you are using azure vnet and its subnet.

Add on's you can use as per your requirement but please ensure you have used data block for workspace otherwise you can directly give the resourceID. So, instead of

```
log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.insights.id
```

you can use

```
log_analytics_workspace_id = "/subscriptions/SubscriptionID/resourcegroups/resourcegroupname/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/workspacename"
```

**Example to create private cluster with existng vnet and subnets (I haven't added add on's):**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

#resource group as this will be referred to in managed identity creation
data "azurerm_resource_group" "base" {
  name     = "resourcegroupname"
}

#exisiting vnet
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "base" {
  name                = "ansuman-vnet"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.base.name
}

#exisiting subnets

data "azurerm_subnet" "aks" {
  name                 = "akssubnet"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.base.name
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.base.name
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "firewall" {
  name                 = "AzureFirewallSubnet"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.base.name
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.base.name
}

#user assigned identity required to create route table

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "base" {
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.base.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.base.location
  name                = "mi-name"
}

#role assignment required to create route table

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "base" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_resource_group.base.id
  role_definition_name = "Network Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.base.principal_id
}

#route table

resource "azurerm_route_table" "base" {
  name                = "rt-aksroutetable"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.base.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.base.name
}

#route 

resource "azurerm_route" "base" {
  name                   = "dg-aksroute"
  resource_group_name    = data.azurerm_resource_group.base.name
  route_table_name       = azurerm_route_table.base.name
  address_prefix         = "0.0.0.0/0"
  next_hop_type          = "VirtualAppliance"
  next_hop_in_ip_address = azurerm_firewall.base.ip_configuration.0.private_ip_address
}

#route table association

resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "base" {
  subnet_id      = data.azurerm_subnet.aks.id
  route_table_id = azurerm_route_table.base.id
}

#firewall

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "base" {
  name                = "pip-firewall"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.base.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.base.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_firewall" "base" {
  name                = "fw-akscluster"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.base.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.base.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                 = "ip-firewallakscluster"
    subnet_id            = data.azurerm_subnet.firewall.id
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.base.id
  }
}

#kubernetes_cluster

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "base" {
  name                    = "testakscluster"
  location                = data.azurerm_resource_group.base.location
  resource_group_name     = data.azurerm_resource_group.base.name
  dns_prefix              = "dns-testakscluster"
  private_cluster_enabled = true

  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "azure"
    outbound_type  = "userDefinedRouting"
  }


  default_node_pool {
    name           = "default"
    node_count     = 1
    vm_size        = "Standard_D2_v2"
    vnet_subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.aks.id
  }

  identity {
    type                      = "UserAssigned"
    user_assigned_identity_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.base.id
  }
  depends_on = [
      azurerm_route.base,
      azurerm_role_assignment.base
    ]
}
```

**Output:**

**(Terraform Plan)**

[image]

**(Terraform Apply)**

[image]

**(Azure portal)**

[image]

**Note:**  Its bydefault that azure requires the subnet name for firewall to be `AzureFirewallSubnet`. If you are using subnet with any other name for firewall creation then it will error out. So, Please ensure to name the existing subnet to be used by firewall to be `AzureFirewallSubnet`.

Comment: i have to use kubenet only no other option   network_profile {
    network_plugin = "kubenet"
    load_balancer_sku = "Standard"
    outbound_type  = "userDefinedRouting"
    network_policy = "calico"
    pod_cidr       = "10.244.0.0/16"
    service_cidr   = "10.0.0.0/16"
    dns_service_ip = "10.0.0.10"
    docker_bridge_cidr = "172.17.0.1/16"
  }